# How do you run a git connection / credential check?

Tags: git

I want to test that a set of git credentials work, but my computer is set up to work with some default credentials. How can i run a git connection check?

I've tried setting:

```
[credential]
    username = example
```

but it still successfully runs a pull, i guess it's using the global credentials but i'm not sure where these are stored.

Is there a quick command to just test credentials? This is ideally what i'm looking for

Comment: I think the GitHub and Bitbucket APIs probably have endpoints which can be used to "ping" those servers.  At least, Jenkins/TeamCity have buttons for testing credentials, so something suitable must exist.

Comment: I'm specifically concerned with testing against VSO. but i'm fine to even pull on a repository, but it seems to succeed even though my username is "example" in the local config file??

Comment: Then it must not be using those credentials.

Comment: Exactly. That's the problem i'm asking about :) ? How do i make it use the credentials ?

Comment: Do you have credential helper running in the background?  You might see some output from it when you first start up the Git bash.

Comment: What is credential helper?

Comment: I'm not really sure/I don't really remember.  I installed it somewhat recently.  It comes from a script which loads your credentials whenever the Git Bash starts.  This is one candidate for what could be overriding the file you pasted above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an arg to your git command to disable all credential helpers so you get prompted for credentials, e.g.

```
git -c 'credential.helper=' fetch
```

(`-c` is a way of adding a config value just for that command)